# Existence of Continuous Function Mapping one function to Another

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions.  When does there exist a continuous function $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h\circ f = g$?

---

Here's what I've noticed so far... If $f$ admits a continuous right-inverse $F$ then we may set $h=g\circ F$.  However, this is a rather strong requirement and I expect that only the intermediate value theorem is needed ... but I'm not sure where to proceed from this point.